# Increase Aggregation Framework Performance in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have 200k records in my collection. My data model looks like as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51750ec159dcef125863b7c4"),
    "DateAdded" : ISODate("2013-04-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "DateRemoved" : ISODate("2013-12-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "DealerID" : ObjectId("51750bd559dcef07ec964a41"),
    "ExStockID" : "8324482",
    "Make" : "Mazda",
    "Model" : "3",
    "Price" : 11479,
    "Year" : 2012,
    "Variant" : "1.6d (115) TS 5dr",
    "Turnover": 150
}
```

I have several indexes for the collection, one of those used for aggregation framework is:

```
{
    "DealerID" : 1,
    "DateRemoved" : -1,
    "Price" : 1,
    "Turnover" : 1
}
```

The aggregate query which is being used:

```
db.stats.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "DealerID": {
            "$in": [
                ObjectId("523325ac59dcef1b90a3d446"),
                ....
                // here is specified more than 150 ObjectIds
            ]
        },
        "DateRemoved": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2013-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
},
{ "$project" : { "Price":1, "Turnover":1 } },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "Price": {
            "$avg": "$Price"
        },
        "Turnover": {
            "$avg": "$Turnover"
        }
    }
}]);
```

and the time for this query executions resides between 30-200 seconds.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: just a test here, if you remove the $avg operators is it fast?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `.explain()` on aggregation. But you could execute the $match as a normal `collection.find` followed by `.explain()` to get a hopefully helpful explain output telling you if the index is effective.

Comment: $project and $group don't benefit from indexes, so when you created that index especially for this query, it would likely work better (or at least just as well) without `Price` and `Turnover`.

Comment: @Philipp you can actually use explain, it just doesn't work across sharding

Comment: @Philipp  With no intention to argue, just wonder why $project donesn't benefit from the index ?  Looks like Miro was trying to create a covering index here. $project should use the index to avoid lookups to the actual documents

Comment: @MaksymStrukov The entire documents will be passed to the next pipline, for example two successive matches will mean the last match will not use an index, though that behaviour has been changed so those two matches get merged now

Comment: @Sammaye if `$avg` changed to `$sum` it didn't help a lot

Comment: No remove them entirely, just do the group without the sumand avg, just the null grouping, I have seen before where double summing/avging seems to create a really slow query

Comment: @Philipp if `Price` and `Turnover` are excluded from index, query works more slow.

Comment: @Sammaye the null grouping query has been executed twice and first time it took 38 sec and second time 17 sec for execution.

Comment: Hmm that is way too slow, I mean that killer slow, however you can remove that project operator you don't actually need it, it might actually result in less performance. Have you tested the query uses all the right indexes and that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run explain on the aggregation pipeline, but as I don't have your full dataset, I can't try it out properly:

```
p = [
{
    "$match": {
        "DealerID": {
            "$in": [
                ObjectId("51750bd559dcef07ec964a41"),
                ObjectId("51750bd559dcef07ec964a44"),
            ]
        },
        "DateRemoved": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2013-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
},
{ "$project" : { "Price":1, "Turnover":1 } },
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "Price": {
            "$avg": "$Price"
        },
        "Turnover": {
            "$avg": "$Turnover"
        }
    }
}];

db.s.runCommand('aggregate', { pipeline: p, explain: true } );
```

I would suggest to remove the fields that are not part of the $match (Price and Turnover). Also, I think you should switch the order of DealerId and DateRemoved as you want to do *one* range search, and from that range then include all the dealers. Doing it the other way around means that you can really only use the index for the 150 single items, and *then* you need to do a range search.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Derick's answer I have found the index which prevented to create the covered index. As far as I can see query optimizer uses the first index which covers just the query itself, so I have changed the order of indexes. So here is outcome before and after.

Before:

```
{
    "serverPipeline" : [ 
        {
            "query" : {...},
            "projection" : { "Price" : 1, "Turnover" : 1, "_id" : 0 },
            "cursor" : {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor DealerIDDateRemoved multi",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 11036,
                "nscannedObjects" : 11008,
                "nscanned" : 11307,
                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 11201,
                "nscannedAllPlans" : 11713,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexOnly" : false,
                "nYields" : 0,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "millis" : 58,
                "indexBounds" : {...},
                "allPlans" : [...],
                "oldPlan" : {...},
                "server" : "..."
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {...}
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

After these changes `indexOnly` param now shows `true`, this means we have just created the covered index:

```
{
    "serverPipeline" : [ 
        {
            "query" : {...},
            "projection" : { "Price" : 1, "Turnover" : 1, "_id" : 0 },
            "cursor" : {
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor DealerIDDateRemovedPriceTurnover multi",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "n" : 11036,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "nscanned" : 11307,
                "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 285,
                "nscannedAllPlans" : 11713,
                "scanAndOrder" : false,
                "indexOnly" : true,
                "nYields" : 0,
                "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                "millis" : 58,
                "indexBounds" : {...},
                "allPlans" : [...],
                "server" : "..."
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {...}
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now the query works approximately between 0.085-0.300 seconds. Additional information about covered queries [Create Indexes that Support Covered Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries)